# import function from folder in python

Tags: python, import, module

Im trying to import a function located in another folder into my python file which is located in another folder.

Folder structure looks like this

```
Project:
  -dbNameFolder
     + __init__.py
     + dbNames.py
  -FolderIwantToImportTo
     + file.py
```

for example, i tried this with a basic add function

```
def Add(a,b):
   return (a+b)
```

and imported it like so

```
from solve.basic import Add
```

NB: Im importing from a folder into another folder not the root of the project

I'm getting an error saying the function is not found, i tried using sys but its only working in vscode if i do it in pycharm im getting errors.

[image: Preview of file]

[image]

Comment: please, add the import statements, in the form you have tried them, and error messages you got, as printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example, i tried this with a basic add function

```
def Add(a,b):
   return (a+b)
```

> and imported it like so

```
from solve.basic import Add
```

For this to work, the `solve` parent package has to be in sys.path .
The correct way of deterministically fixing these is to turn your project into a real package, and then, in the development environments, install it as an "editable package": all source code packages are then imported by Python from where they are in the disk, and any modifications are automatically taken in account.

Even if the code is not intended to be ever copied to or installed in another computer or directory, that fixes a lot of headaches.

The modern way for a minimal package install is placing, in the folder above your project folder, a `pyproject.toml` file - it can be fairly minimal, and use the traditional `setuptools` stack. Then, on that folder, running the command `pip install -e .` with your working Python (virtualenv, system Python, other custom install, etc...) active. In an IDE, that means going to the terminal provided by the IDE itself and typing that command (on the O.S. shell, not inside a Python (`>>>` prompt) shell).

A minimal `pyproject.toml` file to allow this is:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "solve" 
version = "1.0"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["solve"]
```

And then `pip install -e .` on the folder where this file is. If that errors out, check if you have a note advising to upgrade `pip` itself and do that: `pip install -U pip`, then retry.

(That will work without requiring any `__init__.py` file in the package subfolders. Older Pythons would require such a file, even if it was empty (0 bytes) )

This will allow even for relative imports - for example, in a
`solve/data/dbfile.py`  file you can do   `from ..basic import Add`, along, of course `from solve.basic import Add`.

---

The "incorrect" way that could work if you don't want to deal with `pip install` (you really should), is to add the folder containing `solve` itself to your `sys.path` list of folders. That can be done once on the entry point of your project. Let's say you have a `solve/__init__.py` file - you can include in it:

```
from pathlib import Path

import sys

package_path = str(Path(__file__).parent.parent)
sys.path.insert(0, package_path)

# from here on, "import solve. ..." will work
# (but check the note on the `__init__.py` files above)
```

Comment: Thank you, coming from a ts node environment, importing was never a hustle

Comment: everything is a trade off. Python is certainly short-handed in high-level voluntary contributors to ease package creation and installs - that is why I crafted this minimal pyproject.toml which should be easier to find (eventually pip or other built-in tool could create it automatically). In node as I understand it, one of the trade offs is that one can end up with several copies of the same projects in different subfolders on larger projects.